# Why does my DataTrigger not work in my Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin

Following the documentation from Xamarins website surrounding `DataTriggers` I wanted to implement a solution in my ListView that would check if a `label` had any text in it or not.  If the `Text.Length` is 0 then style a `BoxView` using  the `Setters` as per my code.

```
<Label x:Name="forward_label" Text="{Binding next_charterer_info}" />

<BoxView x:Name="forward_alert" 
         BackgroundColor="Red">
    <BoxView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="BoxView" 
                     Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference forward_label}, 
                               Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </BoxView.Triggers>
</BoxView>
```

So as you can see I have the label which is checked for it's `text.length` and if it's 0 then the `BackgroundColor` of the `BoxView` is set to white.  When I run the application however it's not working.  The condition never seems to be met.  The bound data either has a value or it returns empty string.

Can anyone assist me with where I have gone wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a **ValueConverter**, I think that it could be an easier solution.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourProject.Converters
{
    public class StringLengthToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Color EmptyColor { get; set; }
        public Color DefaultColor { get; set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                return EmptyColor;
            }
            return DefaultColor;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And your page should look like...

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <conv:StringLengthToColorConverter x:Key="StringLengthToColorConverter" EmptyColor="White" DefaultColor="Red" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Label x:Name="forward_label" Text="{Binding next_charterer_info}" />

<BoxView x:Name="forward_alert" 
         BackgroundColor="{Binding next_charterer_info,Converter={StaticResource StringLengthToColorConverter}}">
</BoxView>
```